# Can i create 2 SubDirectories at same time C#?

Tags: c#, create-directory

I want to create a simple directory tree like this one, although it doesn't need to have the same name

[image: Directory Tree]

Do I need to write it like this:

```
Directory.CreateDirectory("/home/XXX/Documents/Users/Pepe/datos/");
Directory.CreateDirectory("/home/XXX/Documents/Users/Juan");
```

Is there any option to create "Pepe" and "Juan" in the same string path?

Comment: No.  But what is the problem with the way you have it?

Comment: you have to use CreateDirectory method every time  you need to create a directory. It is not over engineered, what is the issue?

Comment: If  that is not convenient then create a static method that takes in an array of directories as a string and use that as a convenience method. ie. `public static void CreateDirs(params string[] dirPaths){/* loop over array and create directories*/}`

Comment: I smell homework...

Comment: @MarioDS -- So?

Comment: Isn't the homework argument only for people expecting the code to be written for them? Who cares if this is a "homework" question? How are people expected to learn if they're not allowed ask any questions during the entirety of their college years?

Comment: @ColinM -- Don't worry, there's nothing inherently wrong with asking for help with homework.  I see people like MarioDS commenting like that all the time.  The problem is when they just dump there homework question without much else and expect people to do it for them.

Comment: There is no problem. Is a simple exercise i was wondering if there is a better option for knowledge only, im a curious person .Thx for the -1 ;) ppl are so kind this days

Comment: @VictorMAnuelLimaDelgado -- +1 from me, man.  I think it's a good question.  But I think it might be "lack of research effort" why people dv you.  I think that's lame though; should you always have to say "I googled this and couldn't find an answer"?  That seems like superfluity to me.

Comment: @rory.ap Yeah i googled it and search on this page bcs i was wondering if that will be possible .

Answer (score 4):

To post an answer and offer an alternative, if you only wanted to have one usage of the `CreateDirectory` method then you could have a method that takes a parameter of `params string[]` and pass in the directories there when calling the method.

The code would look like so

```
private static void CreateDirectories(params string[] directories)
{
    foreach (string directory in directories)
    {
        Directory.CreateDirectory(directory);
    }
}
```

You can call it with

```
CreateDirectories("/home/XXX/Documents/Users/Pepe/datos/", "/home/XXX/Documents/Users/Juan");
```

Or you can pass in a string array

```
CreateDirectories(new [] { "/home/XXX/Documents/Users/Pepe/datos/", "/home/XXX/Documents/Users/Juan"});
```

I reduce the usage of the `System.IO` methods doing the above, then I interface the class which allows me to create mocks and then unit test the software I create without performing I/O operation, which brings one scenario where you could use the above except it wouldn't be static.

Answer (score 2):

No there's nothing baked into the BCL to do that; you have to call `CreateDirectory` for every one.

If you have a collection of directory paths, you can put that inside a loop:

```
foreach (string dirPath in directoryPaths)
{
    Directory.CreateDirectory(dirPath);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you have a common root directory:

```
/home/XXX/Documents/Users
```

and you want to add sub-directories from there.  If that is the case and if the goal is to only have to reference the sub-directories, then I would go with @ColinM's approach, but modify it slightly as follows:

```
private static void CreateDirectories(string directoryRoot, params string[] directories)
{
    foreach (string directory in directories)
    {
        Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.Combine(directoryRoot, directory));
    }
}
```

Now when you call it, you only need to mention the root once

```
CreateDirectories("/home/XXX/Documents/Users", "Pepe/datos/", "Juan");
```

The nice thing about `Path.Combine` is that you don't have to worry about having a slash `/`  that is either trailing in the `directoryRoot` or leading in any of the `directories`--it will make sure it is formatted correctly in the end.

Of course, if you take this approach, you'll need to decide what happens if `directories` is null--do you create the directoryRoot (assuming it isn't already there), do you throw an error, or do you just return?

Answer (score 0):

You can create like.

System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory("c:/Dir1/Dir2/Dir3");

Think there is no Dir1 at root of c: drive.

It will create folder structure as like Dir1-->Dir2-->Dir3.

If Die1 is there then it will create rest of sub directory.

Same for multiple level.